# is prime spectrum $Spec(R)$ countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ commutative ring with identity, given $Spec(R)=\{I|\text{$I$ prime ideal of $R$}\}$, does the set $Spec(R)$ countable? Also, if $\{\langle p^n \rangle\}$ is closed in $P_{-}Spec(R) = \{I| \text{$I$ primary ideal of $R$}\}$, does $\langle p^n \rangle$ maximal ideal? I tried to prove it but can't seem to find the answer. Could someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first question, no: take $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ to be a polynomial ring in one variable. The prime ideals are $0$ and those generated by $x-a$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$, of which there are uncountably many.

For the second question, the closed points of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ are precisely the maximal ideals. I don't know what topology you are using on the set of primary ideals. Can you clarify?

Comment: well, for the second question I was working with Hummadi's journal Primary Spectrum. The topology on $P_{-}Spec(R)$ are claimed similar to Zariski Topology, so the topology is constructed by defining the closed set as $V_p(I)=\{P \in P_{-}Spec(R)| I \subseteq P\}$.

Comment: Actually for the first question, I'm trying to prove that the space $P_{-}Spec(R)$ is separable.. It seems like my logic is a bit flawed if the answer is no.

Comment: Well, quite often there is a *generic point* whose closure is the whole space. Does that help you?

Comment: I'm a bit confused when you said that the closed points of $Spec(R)$ are the maximal ideal. Could you explain why?

Comment: The closed sets in the Zariski topology are the sets $V(I)$ consisting of all prime ideals containing an ideal $I$. The closure of a prime ideal $P$ consists exactly of all those prime ideals that contain $P$---this is the smallest set of the form $V(I)$ that contains $P$.

Comment: Oh I see..
now I understand. Thank you very much. (^_^)